# How to create MSI for WPF .Net Core 3 Application?

Tags: wpf, asp.net-core, wix

When working with .Net Framework 4.7 & WPF, we use fody weaver to package up all the project dlls etc... into one dll, so we could then use Wix installer.

This is extremely convenient, and fody worked a treat.

With a .Net Core 3.1 Wpf app I cant get fody to work and they have put it in [maintenance mode](https://github.com/Fody/Costura) because of .net core 3's new single- file exe's.

I can create a single file exe but still need to install my app as its code signed and I want the user experience to be familiar with the standard ms installer ui.

At the moment im sure I can create a Wix project and include all the dll's, but there are hundreds of them with .net core & this is an immense amount of work.

Can anyone shed any light on how to install a .net core 3 WPF app using Wix?

Comment: Have you tried to use `msix` format or use `heat` tool to autogenerate the `wxs` file?

Comment: @ Pavel Anikhouski. Thanks, I looked at msix but my app goes out to win 7 too. heat seems like the tool for the job. I was hoping someone would chirp in and give me a super easy simply quick solution similar to fody :-/ ah well.

Comment: Afaik, `msix` packages is working on win7 as well. I don't think that super easy and simply solution is possible without sharing your application details/structure, etc

Comment: I think the user has to install something to get msix working on W7, i will check it out more. Whilst i have now got heat.exe working, I need a transform to ignore exe, pdb & xml files, which can be done with heats -t switch, but is proving to be such a pain (like most of wix) i ended up using this util instead: https://github.com/aykanatm/WixXmlGenerator Thank you for the pointers

Comment: Check out: https://github.com/iswix-llc/iswix-tutorials